# Migrate date time field using migrate source csv

Tags: 8, migrations, datetime

I am trying to migrate a datetime field from csv file but only few are being migrating and other are being failed.I am using migrate

I have created two datetime fields called as Activation Date and Expiry Date in article content type. Attached field type images for reference.

I am writing a custom migration yml file to migrate data from csv file. But only the date values from id 6-10 are being imported but not the date values from 1-5 .

While import I am getting error stating **article_csv_import Migration - 5 failed.**

I have included sample data and yml file for reference.

Can anyone please let me know what causing the first 5 dates import failing ? Any pointers for a way to debug migration process is greatly appreciated.

**migration_examples/migrations/article_csv_import.yml**

```
id: article_csv_import
label: Import Articles
migration_group: default
migration_tags:
  - Article CSV Migration

source:
  plugin: 'csv'
  # Full path to the file.
  path: public://subscription-list-small-copy.csv
  # Column delimiter. Comma (,) by default.
  delimiter: ','
  enclosure: '"'
  header_offset: 0
  ids:
    - id
  fields:
    0:
      name: id
      label: 'Id'
    1:
      name: title
      label: 'Title'
    2:
      name: body
      label: 'Post body'
    3:
      name: field_activation_date
      label: 'Activation Date'
    4:
      name: field_expiry_date
      label: 'Expiry Date'
process:
  title: title
  body: body
  #activation date of the account.
  field_activation_date:
    -
      plugin: format_date
      from_format: Y-m-d H:i:s
      to_format: 'Y-m-d\TH:i:s'
      from_timezone: 'America/Managua'
      to_timezone: 'UTC'
      source: field_activation_date
  # expiry date of the account.
  field_expiry_date:
    -
      plugin: format_date
      from_format: Y-m-d H:i:s
      to_format: 'Y-m-d\TH:i:s'
      from_timezone: 'America/Managua'
      to_timezone: 'UTC'
      source: field_expiry_date
  type:
    plugin: default_value
    default_value: article

destination:
  plugin: entity:node
```

Sample CSV Data : **subscription-list-small-copy.csv**

```
id,title,body,field_activation_date,field_expiry_date
1,Title 1,Body 1,2012-12-22 2:36:03,2013-01-03 0:00:00
2,Title 2,Body 2,2013-08-16 0:00:00,2013-09-15 0:00:00
3,Title 3,Body 3,2013-09-14 0:00:00,2013-10-14 0:00:00
4,Title 4,Body 4,2014-04-08 0:00:00,2014-04-07 23:59:59
5,Title 5,Body 5,2014-09-30 0:00:00,2015-03-29 11:00:00
6,Title 6,Body 6,2014-12-09 12:29:00,2015-01-09 12:29:00
7,Title 7,Body 7,2014-12-31 11:08:00,2015-06-26 23:59:59
8,Title 8,Body 8,2015-02-25 19:12:00,2015-08-10 23:59:59
9,Title 9,Body 9,2015-03-01 11:19:00,2015-02-28 23:59:59
10,Title 10,Body 10,2015-03-02 18:01:00,2015-08-20 23:59:59
```

[image-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8M1gl.png) [image-2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cQ1dd.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`from_format: Y-m-d H:i:s` means hours with leading zeroes, but there are no leading zeroes in your source. Use `from_format: Y-m-d G:i:s` (capital `G`)  for 24-hour-format without leading zeroes

see https://www.php.net/manual/function.date.php

Comment: Thank you it worked.