# Migration of user, the date cannot be created from a format

Tags: migrations

How to get migration of users from d7 to d10 working. PHP is 8.2.

```
upgrade_d7_user:field_last_updated:sub_process: format_date: Format date plugin could not transform '2022-02-18 16:59:34' using the format 'Y-m-d\TH:i:s'. Error: The date cannot be created from a format.
```

I've created a custom migration module, and a custom version of this module with \T taken out of the format

[image: Custom migration]

```
field_last_updated:
-
  plugin: sub_process
  source: field_last_updated
  process:
    value:
      plugin: format_date
      from_format: 'Y-m-d H:i:s'
      to_format: 'Y-m-d H:i:s'
      source: value
      settings:
        validate_format: false
```

I've uploaded a 'single config item' and run the migration wwg_migrate_user both by using drush and structure > migrations.

The date format is not updated.

[image: Date format not changed]

I'm convinced that the \T is causing problems. Not sure why this database is different, drupal

This is what the debugger tells me the problem is

[image: Migration debug the date]

How to fix? Custom migration plugin to take the T out?

Update

I've created a custom migrate plugin that isn't being called. The custom module is, and the custom migration. Standard FormatDate plugin is being called.

[image: Migration class]

The configuration

[image: Migration configuration]

Ran the configuration import

```
    sh ./src/dr.sh cim -y --partial --source=modules/custom/wwg_migrate/config/install
+------------+-----------------------------------------+-----------+
| Collection | Config                                  | Operation 
|
+------------+-----------------------------------------+-----------+
|            | migrate_plus.migration.wwg_migrate_user | Create    |
+------------+-----------------------------------------+-----------+
```

Comment: Show us the sample of source date

Comment: Format date plugin could not transform '2022-02-18 16:59:34' using the format 'Y-m-d\TH:i:s'. Error: The date cannot be created from a format.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Migrate date time field using migrate source csv](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/299288/migrate-date-time-field-using-migrate-source-csv)

Comment: I'm missing something to do with the mapping of process plugins to actions. The original 'format_date' is being called rather than the 'wwg_format_date' one in my module.

Comment: Works if I take \T out - Hacked the main FormatDate plugin badly.     $toFormatNoT= str_replace('\T', ' ', $toFormat);

Comment: There are leading zeros -  transform '2016-03-22 03:37:39' using the format 'Y-m-dH:i:s'. No tabs. The source website is big and a mess. Still a standard d7.